# Can't initialise \AsyncMysqlQueryResult object

Tags: mysql, hhvm

I want simply initialise the `\AsyncMysqlConnectionResult $connec;` object

```
<?hh

namespace Connection;

require_once("ini.php");

/**
 * Class for execute and fetch query
 */
class MyQuery
{
/**
 * if connection isn't valid recreate pool
 */
private ?\AsyncMysqlConnectionPool $pool;

/**
 * \AsyncMysqlConnection object, store $conn
 */
private \AsyncMysqlConnection $connec;

/**
 * \AsyncMysqlQueryReturn object, store return query
 */
private \AsyncMysqlQueryResult $result;

/**
 * check if $conn object isValid(), if not release
 * connection
 */
public function __construct(\AsyncMysqlConnection $conn)
{
    if ($conn->isValid() == false)
    {
        $this->pool = new MyPool();
        $this->connec = $this->pool->connect();
    }
    else
        $this->connec = $conn;

    $this->result = object;
}

/**
 * escape query and execute it
 */
public async function query(string $query): Awaitable<\AsyncMysqlQueryResult>
{
    $query = $this->connec->escapeString($query);
    echo "Query escape\n";

    /* Try to execute the query, if fail display error */
    try
    {
        $this->result = await $this->connec->query($query);
        //log request with ini
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo "Couldn't execute the request, error with message :<br>";
        var_dump($e->getMessage());
        //log request with fail
    }

    echo "Query done succefully\n";
    return $this->result;
}

/**
 * escape Map array and execute the request
 */
public async function queryf(HH\FormatString<HH\SQLFormatter> $query, array<string> $params): Awaitable<\AsyncMysqlQueryResult>
{
    $i = 0;

    while ($params[$i++])
        $params[$i] = $this->connec->escapeString($params[$i]);

    /* Try to execute the query, if fail display error */
    try
    {
        $result = await $this->connec->queryf($query, implode(', ', $params));
        //log request with ini
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo "Couldn't execute the request, error with message :<br>";
        var_dump($e->getMessage());
        //log request with fail
    }

    echo "Query done succefully\n";
    return $this->result;
}
}

newtype AsyncMysqlConnectionResult = object;
newtype FormatString<T> = string;

async function simple_query(\AsyncMysqlConnection $conn): Awaitable<Vector>
{
    $connec = new MyQuery($conn);
    $ret = await $connec->query('SELECT * FROM users');
    return $ret->vectorRows();
}

function run_query(\AsyncMysqlConnection $conn): void
{
    $r = \HH\Asio\join(simple_query($conn));
    var_dump($r);
}
```

run_query($conn);

For having this object I use [https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/reference/class/AsyncMysqlConnectionPool/connect/](/AsyncMysqlConnectionPool) class and connect() method to have this : \AsyncMysqlConnectionResult $connec object.

I can't find a way to initialise this variable type, I've try to
create newtype AsyncMysqlConnectionResult = object but the filechecker return me : 
`Unbound name: Connection\object (an object type)`

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but there are some examples in the documentation here: https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/async/examples#accessing-mysql

Comment: Thanks for link, I have read a lot a hhvm documentation but not this page. I'm stuck on another problem with the HH\FormatString<HH\SQLFormatter> type of queryf function, I can't send string type to this function, I don't know why the have these complexe type ....

Comment: queryf needs a literal string, so that the format string placeholders can be statically typechecked. Info here: https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/reference/class/AsyncMysqlConnection/queryf/

Comment: Yes a understand, but my problem is to initialise and \AsyncMysqlQueryResult, i don't know how. This variable is important for store query result. I'm trying to initialise it at 'object', the typechecker don't warning this but hhvm return me : Use of undefined constant object - assumed 'object'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only way a find to rewrite queryf() method.

```
public async function queryf($query, array<int, string> $params): Awaitable<\AsyncMysqlQueryResult>
{
    $result = "";

    /* Try to execute the query, if fail display error */
    try // execute query
    {
        $result = await $this->connec->queryf($query, implode(', ', $params));

        // If log_request === TRUE log request with ini
        if ($this->log_request === TRUE)
            await $this->logRequest($query, 0);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) // If the query can't be execute display error
    {
        echo "\nCouldn't execute the request, error with message :<br>\n";
        var_dump($e->getMessage());
        //log request with fail

        await $this->logRequest((string)$query, -1);
    }
    return (object)$result;
}
```

I have no error and everything work fine.
If someone have a better and solution I'm here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the result on the class, why doesn't your query methods simply return the result. For example:

```
public async function query(string $query): Awaitable<\AsyncMysqlQueryResult>
{
    $query = $this->connec->escapeString($query);
    return await $this->connec->query($query);
}
```

or if you really want the result to be stored on the class, make it nullable. This will allow you to not set it in the constructor, and only set it after a query has been made.

```
private ?\AsyncMysqlQueryResult $result;
```

Comment: I'm not forced to stored this variable in class but I can't send to queryf a string, his prototype is : `public function queryf(HH\FormatString<HH\SQLFormatter> $query, ...$args): Awaitable<AsyncMysqlQueryResult>{ }`

Comment: queryf requires a string literal